# How to set AppCompatRadioButton with text on top and change the tint color programatically?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I tried to align text on top in `AppCompatRadioButton` and changing `setSupportButtonTintList` programatically. I got successfully aligned the text top with customizing the AppCompatRadioButton. But now setSupportButtonTintList is not working with this, without customizing the setSupportButtonTintList is working properly.

**acticivity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:text="Top Text"
        android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        AppCompatRadioButton appCompatRadioButton = (AppCompatRadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            int myColor = Color.parseColor("#4caf50");
            appCompatRadioButton.setSupportButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(myColor));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are apply tint for button but as you have set button as null from xml.

```
android:button="@null"
```

So you cannot apply tint to button. You are using drawableBottom for radio button. So you have to apply tint to the drawable at the bottom.

```
android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
```

To apply tint on drawableBottom you have to get bottom drawable first and then apply tint.

```
    AppCompatRadioButton appCompatRadioButton = (AppCompatRadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int myColor = Color.parseColor("#4caf50");
        //appCompatRadioButton.setSupportButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(myColor)); // Your code applying tint to button
        appCompatRadioButton.getCompoundDrawables()[3].setColorFilter(myColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // Applying tint to drawable at bottom. '3' to get drawable at bottom
    }
```

Goodluck :)